# what is the output this null character printing?

Tags: c, printf, null-character

I am expecting a blank space for the `printf("%c",i)` while its clearly returning a value after the evaluation of the statement, So I think it should print a blank like or some other value for that matter as it's not null string it's null character.

All i am saying is printf returns some value when the call completes, as it is a function. so when `printf("%c",i)` is returning some value it should print something.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int  i = 0;
    if(printf("%c",i))
        printf("inside if block");
    else
        printf("inside else block");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about your problem? What do you want and what is happening?

Comment: “%c” - that’s how it’s being processed. Now, what’s the result of printf (per the documentation), and how does this not align with expectations presumed by this code/question?

Comment: ASCII 0 to 31 are known as the "non-printable characters". Why do they have that name, do you think?

Answer (score 4):

> I am expecting a blank space for the printf("%c",i)

`printf("%c",0)` will print the *null character*.  What is seen on a terminal is implementation dependent.  It might be a space, nothing, `␀`, `�`, `^@`, etc.  It has nothing to do with C *strings*.

> i am saying is printf returns some value when the call completes

The *return* value of `printf("%c",i)` is "... the number of characters transmitted, or a negative value if an output
or encoding error occurred." (C17dr § 7.21.6.3 3).  `printf("inside if block");` is certainly executed as a 1 is likely returned from `(printf("%c",i)`.